# Css specificity calculate

Tags: css

All, I was confused by the CSS specificity when encountered with the below code .
Say we have below two css file defined.

In the `A.css` file

```
 #BizIdName
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13 px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In the `B.css` file

```
A {
    font-size: 1em;//browser setting is 16px.
}
```

The Html is below.

```
<a id="BizIdName" href="#">xxxx</a>
```

Based on the CSS specificity, the class in `A.css` is higher specificity than the one in the `B.css` .
So I think if both files are linked in a single Html page. the higher specificity class would overwrite the lower one.

But I don't know why the `font-size: 13 px;` doesn't work. It shows in `16px` instead of `13px`. I don't know if I missed something . If I did, Please kindly tell me why. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the whitespace between the `13` and the `px`. Remove it, then it should work:

```
#BizIdName
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: :))))) I have nothing to say except `haha`

Comment: @Joe.wang whitespaces are always good for readability, but dont use any where grammar prohibits them :-P

Comment: :)))) Thanks you guys who upvote it for me. Seems I found an easy way to get point in SO.

Comment: @Joe.wang You ask for rep, or you ask for solutions?

Comment: @Joe.wang As this answer solved your problem, please consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Seriously speaking .In every question I asked before , I expected I can learn more from the answers, Thanks all the people who upvote or downvote me. Because I always learning something from you. BTW sometimes I would make the stupid mistake like it.

Comment: @bwoebi Yes.  Before we can mark an answer .It is necessary to wait a few minutes after the question posted. Thank you very much!